# Django how the urls are resolved?

Tags: django

Im reviewing a sample DJango code and trying to understand how the urls are resolved?

list.html

#### Categories

```
{% for c in active_categories %}
    <a href="{{c.get_absolute_url}}">{{c.name}}</a><br />
{% endfor %}
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import *

urlpatterns = patterns('ecomstore.catalog.views',
            (r'^$','index',{'template_name':'catalog/index.html'},'catalog_home'),
            (r'^category/(?P<category_slug>[-\w]+)/$','show_category',{'template_name':'catalog/category.html'},'catalog_category'),
            (r'^product/(?P<product_slug>[-\w]+)/$','show_product',{'template_name':'catalog/product.html'},'catalog_product'),
            )
```

The above html list all the categories without any problem and its called when I enter the following in the browser..[http:127.0.0.1:8000]

When I hover over - a href="{{p.get_absolute_url}} - I get the url resolved to--[http://127.0.0.1:8000/category/electronics/]

The p.get_absolute_url is resolved only to electronics but Im wondering how "category" is resolved in the url..

models.py

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=50,unique=True,help_text='Unique value for product page URL created from name')
    description = models.TextField()
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    meta_keywords = models.CharField("Meta Keywords",max_length=255,help_text="comma-delimited set of SEO Keywords for meta tag")
    meta_description = models.CharField("Meta description",max_length=255,help_text="Content for description meta tag")
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'categories'
        ordering = ['-created_at']
        verbose_name_plural = 'Categories'

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

    @models.permalink
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return ('catalog_category',(),{'category_slug':self.slug})
```

Hope my question is clear...

Comment: what does the `get_absolute_url` method look like on the Product object (`models.py`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`get_absolute_url` is a function defined inside the model (for example, `Category`) model like this:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    ...

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return "/category/%s/" % self.slug
```

It is also possible to use `reverse` function to resolve the url using a pattern defined in `urls.py`:

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('catalog_category', args=[str(self.slug)])
```

which is almost equal to an old-fashioned form:

```
@models.permalink
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return ('catalog_category', (), {'category_slug': str(self.slug)})
```

In both ways, calling the `get_absolute_url` method on a Category object, for example `Category(name="electronics")`, will result in the string: `/category/electronics/`.

As you can see in your `urls.py`, the second url pattern is named `catalog_category`, which appeard in the reverse function argument. When you call the reverse function, Django will look into urls.py files, looking for a pattern named `catalog_category`, and the final url will be generated by replacing the url parameter (category_slug) with self.slug.

Comment: I have added models.py...Yes, get_Absolute_url..gets the url..but how the path gets resolved?

Comment: Wow, are you sure? The URL must be resolved to /product/[product_slug]/ according to the model.